# How many $13$ card hands have an ace and a king of the same suit?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have the following question, and my current attempt to the solution is:

Choose an ace out of $4$ aces and then choose one king and then choose $11$ cards randomly out of remaining $44$ cards, which is:

$$\binom41  \binom{44}{11}$$

Comment: You are double-counting hands with the ace of hearts, ace of clubs, king of hearts and king of clubs.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: I don't know how to fix the problem of double counting. Do you suggest other approach?

Comment: The usual approach is inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: So to calculate the hands that have ace and king of same suit I take total numbers of ace and king pair possible (8C2) and subtract them from the cases when ace and king are of different suits (12)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to inclusion-exclusion is to first count the complementary number of ways to *avoid* having an Ace and King of the same suit, organizing this count according to the number of Aces that are chosen, which ranges from $0$ to $4$.  In general, if you choose $k$ Aces, then, in order to avoid any Ace-King matches, the other $13-k$ cards need to be chosen from among the $48-k$ cards that are neither Aces nor the chosen Aces' matching Kings. The total complementary count is thus

$${4\choose0}{48\choose13}+{4\choose1}{47\choose12}+{4\choose2}{46\choose11}+{4\choose3}{45\choose10}+{4\choose4}{44\choose9}$$

and so the count you want is

$${52\choose13}-\left({4\choose0}{48\choose13}+{4\choose1}{47\choose12}+{4\choose2}{46\choose11}+{4\choose3}{45\choose10}+{4\choose4}{44\choose9}\right)$$

Note, however, that in this case the inclusion-exclusion approach, as in drhab's answer, involves fewer terms (four terms to be added or subtracted, instead of six).

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ denote the $13$ card hands having ace and king of spades.

Let $D$ denote the $13$ card hands having ace and king of diamonds.

Let $H$ denote the $13$ card hands having ace and king of hearts.

Let $C$ denote the $13$ card hands having ace and king of clubs.

Then by [inclusion/exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) and symmetry we find:$$|S\cup D\cup H\cup C|=\binom41|S|-\binom42|S\cap D|+\binom43|S\cap D\cap H|-\binom44|S\cap D\cap H\cap C|$$

Can you take if from here?

Comment: Thank you. But I don’t the understand the formula that you came up with

Comment: Do you understand that $|S\cup D\cup H\cup C|=|S|+|D|+|H|+|C|-|S\cap D|-|S\cap H|-\cdots +|S\cap D\cap H|+\cdots-|S\cap D\cap H\cap C|$ according to the principle of inclusion/exclusion?